# Why is a particular argument in my model not going through and causing an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe into my Rails app, and when I try to run my payment form, I get the following error in my Stripe log:

{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "You must supply a valid card"
  }

with this request body:

{
  "plan": "1",
  "description": "jjets718@yahoo.com"
}

I realize that in the request body I should have the token that Stripe gave me when I submitted the credit card information in the payment form. When I save my payment in my controller, I use the following method that I define in my model:

```
def save_with_payment
 if valid?
   customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: 1, card: stripeToken)
   self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
   save!
 end
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
  errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
  false
   end
```

If someone can help me figure out why the Stripe token isn't being submitted to Stripe when I create a customer, and how I can fix the underlying error, that would be great. My Stripe javascript produces a Stripe token with the name 'stripeToken'; so the problem must be in how the controller is getting the token and creating a customer.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
    <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // this identifies your website in the createToken call below
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_gV4NDoU8ymr5md49FJeNb5E1lIAda');

        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                // re-enable the submit button
                $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
                // show the errors on the form
                $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
            } else {
                var form$ = $("#payment-form");
                // token contains id, last4, and card type
                var token = response['id'];
                // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
                // and submit
                form$.get(0).submit();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
                // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
                $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                // createToken returns immediately - the supplied callback submits the form if there are no errors
                Stripe.createToken({
                    number: $('.card-number').val(),
                    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
                }, stripeResponseHandler);
                return false; // submit from callback
            });
        });

        if (window.location.protocol === 'file:') {
            alert("stripe.js does not work when included in pages served over file:// URLs. Try serving this page over a webserver. Contact support@stripe.com if you need assistance.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you assigning the value of stripeToken returned by Stripe.js to a hidden input?

Comment: I am assigning the value of stripeToken in a hidden input. I'm going to post my javascript file. Do you mind taking a look at that and seeing if you find anything wrong?

Comment: Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: 1, card: stripeToken) Is stripeToken a method on the class that the save_with_payment is in? How is params[:stripeToken] making it to Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: 1, card: stripeToken)?